# I want the second widget(container) to be aligned to the left but it's aligned to the center. How can I align it to the left along other widgets?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to align the container commented "// add student button" to the left but it aligns to center.
I have also tried using a raised button insted but in that case it extends to the full parent container length but I only want it to clip to the button content.

```
import 'package:educewebsite/SizeConfig.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StudentsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StudentsScreenState createState() => _StudentsScreenState();
}

class _StudentsScreenState extends State<StudentsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 90,
      width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 80,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2),
      child:
          Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
        // top title
        ListTile(
            leading: Icon(
              Icons.people,
              size: 40,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Students',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22),
            )),
        // add new student button
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 8,
          width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 15,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
          child: ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.person_add, color: Colors.white, size: 35),
              title: Text(
                'Add Student',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              )),
        ),
        //search student form
        Container(
          child: Text('this is here'),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 2.5,
              horizontal: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 1),
          height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 65,
          width: SizeConfig.blockSizeHorizontal * 80,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.black12),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        )
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your container is using center:              
    alignment: Alignment.center

Comment: That's for its child widget I'm talking abhout the containers placement in the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wrap your "Add student button" container in Align Widget.
Ex:-

```
Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container() // Add Student Button Container,
          ),
```